# Laravel delete file while developing windows

Tags: laravel-6

In my local development environment (xampp, windows) I have the file

> D:\Documents\repos\somerepo\public\img\bathroom\8\small\someimage.jpg

I try to delete it with:

```
Storage::delete(public_path('img/bathroom/8/small/someimage.jpg'));
```

However the file still exists after running the code.
When I print the path of `public_path('img/bathroom/8/small/someimage.jpg')` And copy it inside file explore it opens the file just fine.
How can I make laravel delete the file?

When I run:

```
    if(File::exists($path)){
        return $path." Does not exist";
    }
```

Where path is `public_path('img/bathroom/8/small/someimage.jpg')` it tells me it does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using the default filesystem configuration, [the `public` disk](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/filesystem#the-public-disk) stores files in `storage/app/public`.  [The `local` disk](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/filesystem#the-local-driver) uses `storage/app`.  In short, both local disks manage files under `storage/`.

[The `public_path()` helper](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/helpers#method-public-path) returns the fully qualified path to the public directory.  So:

```
public_path('img/bathroom/8/small/someimage.jpg')
```

will generate a path like this:

```
/your/project/public/img/bathroom/8/small/someimage.jpg
```

Note that this is *not* under `storage/`, where both `Storage` local disks operate.  Passing `Storage` a fully qualified path outside the root of the filesystem it manages will not work.

To work with files *outside* the roots of the disks that `Storage` is configured for, you will have to use standard PHP functions like `unlink()`, etc.  Alternatively, move the files you want to maintain with `Storage` into one of the disks it is configured for, [add the symlink](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/filesystem#the-public-disk) to make them visible, and update the references to those files in your views etc.

Comment: I currently have my files under public not storage, I will try to find out how workign with storage works.